# USB Keyboard not working with old pc

Tags: usb, keyboard, bios, motherboard

I recently bought an USB keyboard Genius Slimstar 126 for my older computer. Unfortunately it doesn't work with that old pc. It doesn't work in neither system (I tried Win 7 and Linux Mint) or the BIOS.
However if I plug it into my newer laptop or PC, it works completely fine. Other USB keyboards work with that computer, just this one doesn't.

I tried different ports and USB legacy support in bios is enabled.

How is it possible that pc does not recognize this keyboard?

---

*Motherboard: MSI K9N6SGM-V*

*CPU: AMD Athlon 64 x2 4200+*

Comment: Weird indeed. The motherboard is old but should support any USB peripheral anyway. And it does work with other USB keyboards according to you so why it doesn't recognize this one is a mystery. Installing the latest BIOS may or may not solve it: https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/K9N6SGMV__K9N6PGMFI__K9N6PGMF#down-bios

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thank you for you answer. I have already the latest BIOS version installed.

Comment: Then I'm afraid there's nothing else to try.

Comment: You *could* use an adapter to connect that keyboard to the PS2 port.  I myself have some of those adapters laying around as I never use them anymore.  You might see if anyone you know has one laying around.  If you buy one.. they are as little as 2USD.  If I were you, I would stop trying to make a mediocre keyboard work and buy a cheap one that does work.